# opa: asking user details via a form and save it to a database

Tags: database, forms, opa

How can I ask users some data (with some fields that can be modified afterwards), store it in a database and then show some of the collected data to the site users so that all of the db contents are not exposed in the page source code?

Here's a complete example, after a page reload all the data is visible in the page source:

```
import stdlib.crypto

type user= {md5sum: string; name: string; email: string; is_achy: bool }
db /users : stringmap(user);
db /users[_]/is_achy = {false}

setup_page()=
(
  <div id=#users>
    <div class="container">
    <table id=#lista >
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>      
      <th>Headache?</th>      
    </tr>
    {list_db()}    
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>
    Not on the list? Add it here.
    </p>
    <p>
    <input id=#username value="default"/>
    <input id=#email_address value="default@def.ault/>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick={_ -> add_user()} />
    </p>
  </div>
)

list_db()=
(  
  List.map(
    users -> <tr> <th>{users.name}</th> <th><input type="checkbox" id=#{users.md5sum} onclick={_ -> is_achy(users.md5sum)}/></th></tr>, StringMap.To.val_list(/users)
  )
)

add_user() =
(
  name = Dom.get_value(#username)
  md5sum = Crypto.Hash.md5(name)
  email = Dom.get_value(#email_address)  
  if name != "" then 
    do /users[md5sum] <- {~md5sum ~name ~email is_achy=false}
  Dom.transform([{Dom.select_body()} <- setup_page()])
)

is_achy(md5sum) =
(
  /users[md5sum]/is_achy <- Dom.is_checked(Dom.select_id(md5sum))

)

server = one_page_server("Achy head?", setup_page)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully: when does this JS show up in the page? Clearly not on the first view of the page, right? Can you pls post a working (complete but minimal) example and explain what you do to see this JS code?

Comment: @akoprowski Alright, did a bit reformatting and added a complete example. After making an addition to the database and reloading the page, the source code contains javascript with all the values of the db. I did realize that it has something to do with the is_achy() function since without it, nothing is shown in the sources. That was something that I (naively) left out of the equation on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running under the assumption that what you are upset about is that the emails are visible in the sources, as all the other data you are displaying, so it's hardly a surprise that they are ending up on the client.

Why do the emails make it to the client? I thought that marking the `list_db` function as server-side would resolve that but it's not the case and to be honest, I'm not sure why. I'll have to do a bit more digging or try to ask somebody better informed than I am. A simple (though not very satisfactory) work-around would be to make a function that projects the `user` type into something that is needed for the rendering in the browser and to make this projection on the server. It could look something like this:

```
@server users_data() =
(
  StringMap.map(user -> {md5sum=user.md5sum; name=user.name; is_achy=user.is_achy}, /users)
  |> StringMap.To.val_list
)

list_db()=
(
  render_user(user) =
    <tr>
      <th>{user.name}</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id=#{user.md5sum} onclick={_ -> is_achy(user.md5sum)}/></th>
    </tr>
  List.map(render_user, users_data())
)
```

You will see that now the emails don't "leak" into the client. I'll try to come up with a better answer though...

Comment: Yeah, you assumed correctly. I was wondering also why the `@server` directive didn't have any effect. I'll give the workaround a spin, It'll probably be enough for my use case, thank you.